# Refresh table after post

Tags: datatable, settimeout

I developed a table for my **notefrais**, but the problem is when I add **notefrais**, the table doesn't refresh automatically. Is it necessary to refresh the page to display the new **notefrais**? How  can I modify my code to refresh this table automatically? (I work with angular)

The error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'draw' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw' of
>   undefined

```
async ngOnInit() {
    let id = localStorage.getItem('userId');
     ...
     ...
    this.notes = await this._dashbordService.getNotes(id);
     ...
    setTimeout(function () {
      this.table = $('#example-table').DataTable({
        pageLength: 2,
        "bLengthChange": false,
      });
    }, 1000);
}

 async processAdd() {
    let nf = new NoteDeFrais();
    let frm = this.addfrm.value;
    nf.UserId = this.userId;
    ...
    ...
    this._dashbordService.addNoteFrais(nf);
    this.refreshTable(); // for refresh table after add notefrais but don't work !
}

async refreshTable() {
    let id = localStorage.getItem('userId');
    this.notes = await this._dashbordService.getNotes(id);
    this.table.draw(); // the same problem for this.table.reload()
 }
```

Comment: Angular automatically detects change inside your component. As well as you are not using right approach to render data. In my case I used **async pipe** for asynchronous data as well as used **Observable Array** to make it happen correctly. https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe